# systemd service does not trigger the tmux command upon reboot

Tags: bash, systemd, tmux, wvdial

I am using a Yocto image based on the `linux-mainline` kernel. I have `systemd` on the embedded OS that I have created.

#### Aim

I have a UMTS dongle connected to the board which will use `usb_modeswitch` to recognise the dongle and `wvdial` to connect to the 3G insfrastructure.

#### Method

I wrote a simple bash script in `/usr/umts.sh` as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1;
usb_modeswitch --default-vendor 12d1 --default-product 1446 -J

sleep 1;
/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s Cloud
/usr/bin/tmux set-option set-remain-on-exit on
/usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'wvdial' -t Cloud:1 'sleep 1; /usr/bin/wvdialconf; /usr/bin/wvdial';
```

`usb_modeswitch` will configure the USB Dongle and the next part will create a `tmux` session and trigger `wvdial` within.

my `systemd` script looks like follows in `/etc/systemd/system/enable-umts.service`

GNU nano 2.2.5                                                        File: /etc/systemd/system/enable-umts.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable UMTS Dongle for Cloud Connectivity

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/umts.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

(I have given execution rights to the script using `chmod +x /usr/umts.sh`)

I reloaded the daemon `systemctl daemon-reload` and enabled the service `systemctl enable enable-umts.service`

and rebooted the board (NOTE: I have only `root` on board and no other `user`)

The `dmesg` infact triggers the `usb_modeswitch` from the script above and I see related messages

```
[  OK  ] Started Enable UMTS Dongle for Cloud Connectivity.
[   13.051247] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.5
[   13.067326] usb-storage 1-1:1.6: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   13.074645] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-1:1.6
[   13.158627] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[   13.165501] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   13.174754] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   13.202356] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[   13.208714] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[   13.216468] option 1-1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   13.229840] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   13.238774] option 1-1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   13.248906] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   13.256172] option 1-1:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   13.264467] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   14.069960] scsi 2:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   14.088684] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage       PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   14.127686] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   13.238774] option 1-1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   13.248906] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   13.256172] option 1-1:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) coPassword
```

But upon login I try to list the sessions `tmux ls` and it states there are no sessions created.

The `script in fact does not fail and the service status is as follows:

```
● enable-umts.service - Enable UMTS Dongle for Cloud Connectivity
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/enable-umts.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2018-05-17 12:52:10 UTC; 4min 51s ago
  Process: 214 ExecStart=/usr/umts.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 214 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 17 12:52:09 phyboard-mira-imx6-3 umts.sh[214]: Set up interface 0
May 17 12:52:09 phyboard-mira-imx6-3 umts.sh[214]: Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
May 17 12:52:09 phyboard-mira-imx6-3 umts.sh[214]: Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
May 17 12:52:09 phyboard-mira-imx6-3 umts.sh[214]:  OK, message successfully sent
May 17 12:52:09 phyboard-mira-imx6-3 umts.sh[214]: Reset response endpoint 0x81
May 17 12:52:09 phyboard-mira-imx6-3 umts.sh[214]: Reset message endpoint 0x01
May 17 12:52:09 phyboard-mira-imx6-3 umts.sh[214]:  Could not reset endpoint (probably harmless): -99
May 17 12:52:09 phyboard-mira-imx6-3 umts.sh[214]:  Device is gone, skip any further commands
May 17 12:52:09 phyboard-mira-imx6-3 umts.sh[214]: -> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
May 17 12:52:10 phyboard-mira-imx6-3 systemd[1]: Started Enable UMTS Dongle for Cloud Connectivity.
```

If execute the script `/usr/umts.sh` as a standalone script then in fact it does everything it is supposed to do (open a new `tmux` session and triggers `wvdial`)

What is wrong here? I tried adding more `sleep` time but that isn't working either. Sadly there is no `rc.local` or `cron` available for the yocto image I am working on.

Comment: You can try using `tmux -v ...`. It will create 2 files tmux-* in the current directory of the command. This log is very verbose and not very comprehensible but may give a clue as to why it fails, or even if it ran.

Comment: I added `RemainAfterExit=true` in my `systemd` script and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `RemainAfterExit=yes|true` in my `systemd` Script as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable UMTS Dongle for Cloud Connectivity

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/umts.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Added full paths to the `umts.sh` script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

    sleep 1;
    /usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s Cloud
    /usr/bin/tmux set-option set-remain-on-exit on
    /usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'usb_modeswitch' -t Cloud:2 '/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch --default-vendor 12d1 --default-product 1446 -J';

    /usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'wvdial' -t Cloud:1 'sleep 10; /usr/bin/wvdialconf; /usr/bin/wvdial';
```

Reloaded the daemon

`systemctl daemon-reload`

and rebooted the board. and Found the `tmux` sessions created and running perfectly